# New water pressure regulator doesn't change water pressure

Tags: plumbing

I checked the water pressure to my home a few weeks ago, it read 120, and was unable to change the pressure when I adjusted the bolt. I figured the regulator went bad, so I bought a new one.

I installed it today, and I'm having the exact same problem. No matter if the bolt is all the way in, or all the way out, the pressure still reads 120 PSI.

As I turned the water off, I watched the meter drop, so I don't think it's a bad meter.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: Remember that you must adjust and then open a faucet to let pressure out.  When adjusting pressure downward, even though you’ve adjusted it, pressure already there must be let out before you’ll see a change on the gauge.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that I do this after I adjust.

Comment: Are you sure your utility provides higher pressures? 8Bar is quite high for home use.  Some provides only quite low pressure (3 Bar) and to rise it you need to install an autoclave.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Could you post a picture of this water regulator that you're adjusting? Is it on the main entrance of the home, or somewhere else?

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question. Stack Exchange has no problem with self-answers.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem: I had installed the regulator backwards. Leaving this post up in case any others decide not to read directions, or disregard common sense, and have the same problem. Look for the water flow arrows on the regulator.